# how to access the content of the clicked element in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

in the table I have used `ng-repeat` in `<tr>` element. the content in columns are loaded dynamically from a json file. there is a column ID in the table. In the result I have many rows with the different Id in the table.  I want to access the inner html of respective row of the Id column when it is clicked. is there any way ?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat = "x in tableData">
    <td>{{x.id}}</td>
    <td>{{x.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

this is my code. I want to access inner HTML of each Id when it is clicked. Is there any way ?

Answer (score 1):

Add an ng-click event listener to the `td` and pass the value of the td

```js
angular.module("Demo", []).controller("DemoController", ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.tableData = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'name1'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'name2'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'name3'
    }
  ]
  $scope.getData = function(val) {
    console.log(val)
  }
}])
```

```css
td {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Demo" ng-controller="DemoController">

  <table border="1px solid black">
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in tableData">
      <td ng-click='getData(x.id)'>{{x.id}}</td>
      <td>{{x.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```